# Cannot not access (404) PDF file on production server (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've added one folder "Manuals" to my ASP.NET MVC project. In this folder I have two pdf files.

In my view I have links like that:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Manuals/manual1.pdf")">XXXXXXX</a>
```

As far I can see the links are generated property. On my development server:

```
<a href="http://localhost/Manuals/manual1.pdf">XXXXXXX</a>
```

On production server:

```
<a href="http://mysecretappaddress.com/Manuals/manual1.pdf">XXXXXXX</a>
```

Checked on production server and the pdf's are present. But here is the problem - I can access pdf's on my local server, but on production server I get 404 error. What can cause that strange behaviour?

Comment: You should check mime type for pdf on web server IIS on production machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add MIME type in web.config. I think MIME type may be missing on IIS.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".pdf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".pdf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

IIS blocks unknown extensions by default, and throws a 404.3 error. To 'fix' this, you can add this to the web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>        
   <staticContent>            
     <mimeMap fileExtension=".pdf" mimeType="application/pdf" />        
   </staticContent>    
</system.webServer>
```

[More on this blog post](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx)